# How can i make a variable pagination within a form?

Tags: php

i have page that contains a form, it works fine. but i want to add pagination to it.
i've found an pagination example on the web. but, when i change the page, the values from the form are discarded, and i have to recomplete the form on the page that i want to.

i want to add pagination for 50 or 100 rows.

Any tips?

thanks,
Sebastian

**EDIT**

i do submit the form. i want to use any way to paginate. add a drop box in the form, or an live drop box, below the table.
after i submit the form, a table is printed with the entries from my database.

Comment: do you mean you have forms on all different pages but need to remember the values? Like a booking system? If so you could save the values to a session on each page...

Comment: i guess it's an different page. the pagination script that i've found adds to my address bar `?page=1` how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think he's submitting the form, but clicking a link?

Whatever, as Swhistlesoft points out, you need to carry over the form values into the next page.

If you're not submitting the form to load the next page, instead just clicking a "NEXT" link your best bet is probably a javascripted onclick event to add the contents of the form to the link as a $_GET[] URL rewriting appendage thing.

?page=2&formvalue=x&formvalue2=y&formvalue3=foo etc.

then of course you'll need to get the landing page to re-insert this data into the form on generation.

Comment: of course the javascript could also write to a cookie, the point is your data needs to be available to the landing page in order to repopulate the form values

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use sessions ( or cookies ) to save the previous page form values. Using sessions is probably the easiest as you can assign an array to the $_SESSION global variable.

Then all you need to do is add some inline php code to each field to check if a value exists for that form field and echo it to the value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way, but this will definitely look good.  Have a big div with overflow:hidden, then have the pagination as buttons with onclick function to move the div's margin up and down thereby giving a feeling of pagination.  Its an illusion without doing any dirty hacks to pass the data.

Comment: I like this idea, but if the paginated pages are big or if there are a lot of them, this could have a pageload implication. This could be the reason for the pagination in the first place I guess. (course the div could be populated via ajax calls onclick too, to overcome this and of course keep this effect without leaving the page)

Comment: Yeah, that too.  The other reason for pagination would be for better UI for not forcing users to scroll down.  In that case this method can result in a better visual outcome